# Hibernate read only session - updating entities

Tags: java, hibernate

We have set all our sessions to read only by calling `setDefaultReadOnly(true)`. However our updates no longer work even after we explicitly call `session.update(entity)`. I can see why this is happening, hibernate does not know that this entity is dirty.

My question is, how can I tell hibernate that I have made changes to this entity which need to be sync'd back? I tried merging the entity with `session.merge(entity)` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Before you change the state of the entity, make it not read-only:  [session.setReadOnly(entity, false)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#setReadOnly%28java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29)

Then edit the entity, and let flush/commit do dirty checking as per usual.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[`session.refresh(entity)`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#refresh%28java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: Do you use a 2nd lvl cache like ehcache?